# How to find the shared elements in a nested Hashmap and a Vec in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust and I want to write a simple lottery program and the logic is as below:

- The participants need to pick 5 numbers
- The first N digits that match the jackpot will receive some prize

How I want to implement it is using Hashmap:

- For each digit, there is a Hashmap that uses the possible number (0 to 9) as the key and a Vec that contains the ticket numbers
- There is a `lottery` Hashmap that contains those hashmaps for easier iteration

What I want to do is:

- Get the list of tickets that matches the 1st digit of the jackpot (`matches_first_1`)
- To get the list of tickets that are matching the first two digits of the jackpot I want to iterate over the `matches_first_1` then from the tickets that picked the same number of the second digits of the jackpot filter the tickets that also exist in the `matches_first_1` and call it `matches_first_2`
- Continue like this until the end

You can find the program that I wrote with some dummy numbers. The program executes but from `matches_first_2` onward it cannot do the filtering correctly as can be seen from the output and I don't know what is wrong. I tried to use `find()` and other methods but that didn't work. Any opinion on why this code doesn't work?

```rust
use std::collections::hash_map::Entry;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let jackpot: [i32; 5] = [5, 3, 6, 9, 9];
    println! ("jackpot: {:?}", jackpot);

    println!("==================================== Lottery (new code)");
    let mut first_num: HashMap<i32, Vec<String>> = HashMap::new();
    let mut second_num: HashMap<i32, Vec<String>> = HashMap::new();
    let mut third_num: HashMap<i32, Vec<String>> = HashMap::new();
    let mut fourth_num: HashMap<i32, Vec<String>> = HashMap::new();
    let mut fifth_num: HashMap<i32, Vec<String>> = HashMap::new();

    let mut lottery: HashMap<i32, HashMap<i32, Vec<String>>> = HashMap::new();
    
    lottery.insert(0, first_num);
    lottery.insert(1, second_num);
    lottery.insert(2, third_num);
    lottery.insert(3, fourth_num);
    lottery.insert(4, fifth_num);
    println!("{:?}",lottery);

    for i in 0..10 {
        lottery.get_mut(&0).unwrap().insert(i, Vec::<String>::new());
        lottery.get_mut(&1).unwrap().insert(i, Vec::<String>::new());
        lottery.get_mut(&2).unwrap().insert(i, Vec::<String>::new());
        lottery.get_mut(&3).unwrap().insert(i, Vec::<String>::new());
        lottery.get_mut(&4).unwrap().insert(i, Vec::<String>::new());
    }

    // add some test data
    let ticket1: [i32; 5] = [5, 3, 0, 9, 1];
    let ticket2: [i32; 5] = [1, 3, 0, 8, 2];
    let ticket3: [i32; 5] = [5, 3, 6, 9, 9];

    for i in 0..5 {
        lottery.get_mut(&(i as i32)).unwrap().get_mut(&ticket1[i]).unwrap().push("ticket1".to_owned());
        lottery.get_mut(&(i as i32)).unwrap().get_mut(&ticket2[i]).unwrap().push("ticket2".to_owned());
        lottery.get_mut(&(i as i32)).unwrap().get_mut(&ticket3[i]).unwrap().push("ticket3".to_owned());
    }
    println!("{:?}",lottery.get(&0));
    println!("{:?}",lottery.get(&1));
    println!("{:?}",lottery.get(&2));
    println!("{:?}",lottery.get(&3));
    println!("{:?}",lottery.get(&4));

    // find the winners
    println!("======================================");
    let matches_first_1 = lottery.get(&0).unwrap().get(&jackpot[0]);
    println!("matches_first_1: {:?}",matches_first_1);
    
    let matches_first_2 = matches_first_1.iter().cloned().filter(|&x| lottery.get(&1).unwrap().get(&jackpot[1]).iter().any(|&x| x==x)).map(|x| x).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    println!("matches_first_2: {:?}",matches_first_2);
    
    let matches_first_3 = matches_first_2.iter().cloned().filter(|&x| lottery.get(&2).unwrap().get(&jackpot[2]).iter().any(|&x| x==x)).map(|x| x).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    println!("matches_first_3: {:?}",matches_first_3);
    
    let matches_first_4 = matches_first_3.iter().cloned().filter(|&x| lottery.get(&3).unwrap().get(&jackpot[3]).iter().any(|&x| x==x)).map(|x| x).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    println!("matches_first_4: {:?}",matches_first_4);
    
    let matches_first_5 = matches_first_4.iter().cloned().filter(|&x| lottery.get(&4).unwrap().get(&jackpot[4]).iter().any(|&x| x==x)).map(|x| x).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    println!("matches_first_5: {:?}",matches_first_5);
}
```

Output:

```bash
jackpot: [5, 3, 6, 9, 9]
==================================== Lottery (new code)
{2: {}, 0: {}, 1: {}, 4: {}, 3: {}}
Some({0: [], 1: ["ticket2"], 2: [], 6: [], 3: [], 7: [], 9: [], 4: [], 8: [], 5: ["ticket1", "ticket3"]})
Some({6: [], 4: [], 0: [], 3: ["ticket1", "ticket2", "ticket3"], 8: [], 1: [], 7: [], 5: [], 2: [], 9: []})
Some({0: ["ticket1", "ticket2"], 6: ["ticket3"], 5: [], 2: [], 4: [], 7: [], 1: [], 8: [], 3: [], 9: []})
Some({1: [], 0: [], 2: [], 6: [], 5: [], 3: [], 4: [], 8: ["ticket2"], 7: [], 9: ["ticket1", "ticket3"]})
Some({5: [], 6: [], 1: ["ticket1"], 8: [], 7: [], 9: ["ticket3"], 2: ["ticket2"], 3: [], 4: [], 0: []})
======================================
matches_first_1: Some(["ticket1", "ticket3"])
matches_first_2: [["ticket1", "ticket3"]]
matches_first_3: [["ticket1", "ticket3"]]
matches_first_4: [["ticket1", "ticket3"]]
matches_first_5: [["ticket1", "ticket3"]]
```

#### Update

Per suggestion, I changed the name of the second `x` variable to `y` but now the output is empty:

```rust
    let matches_first_2 = matches_first_1.iter().cloned().filter(|&x| lottery.get(&1).unwrap().get(&jackpot[1]).iter().any(|&y| x==y)).map(|x| x).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Output:

```bash
matches_first_1: Some(["ticket1", "ticket3"])
matches_first_2: []
matches_first_3: []
matches_first_4: []
matches_first_5: []
```

Regarding using `map`. I use map to create an iterator and then be able to use `collect` to create a collection.

Comment: `x==x` is a tautology. You need to use different variable names.

Comment: I agree, your second `x` variable shadows your first one. Also, what's the purpose of `map(|x| x)`? It does nothing :)

Comment: @Finomnis `map(|x| x)` is `copied()`, no?

Comment: @Jmb `map(|x| *x)` or `map(|&x| x)` is `copied()`.

Comment: Why not use `copied()` then?

Comment: @Finomnis Please read my update

Comment: Forget my comment, that's what happens when answering before fully waking up.

Comment: @AVarf you don't need `map` to create an iterator: you already have one.

Comment: @AVarf The biggest issue is that `iter()` is called on an `Option` type, not a `Vec` type. So `iter()` iterates over `Vecs` not over `i32`, as expected. Which makes your `==` comparison fail, because you compare vectors, not `i32`s.

Comment: Although honestly I still wonder who came up with the idea that `Option` should have an `iter()`... For exactly the reasons seen here, I find that quite dangerous and unintuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code almost works. The problem is that you don't `unwrap` the `matches_first_1`, causing the first `.iter()` to be an `Option::iter` instead of a `Vec::iter`. You made the same mistake after `.get(&jackpot[1])`, that one is also an `Option` and needs to be unwrapped. Or use `[jackpot[1]]` instead, it unwraps automatically.

Your second mistake is that you named both of your variables `x`, shadowing the first one.

With both of those problems fixed, it works:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let jackpot: [i32; 5] = [5, 3, 6, 9, 9];
    println!("jackpot: {:?}", jackpot);

    println!("==================================== Lottery (new code)");
    let first_num: HashMap<i32, Vec<String>> = HashMap::new();
    let second_num: HashMap<i32, Vec<String>> = HashMap::new();
    let third_num: HashMap<i32, Vec<String>> = HashMap::new();
    let fourth_num: HashMap<i32, Vec<String>> = HashMap::new();
    let fifth_num: HashMap<i32, Vec<String>> = HashMap::new();

    let mut lottery: HashMap<i32, HashMap<i32, Vec<String>>> = HashMap::new();

    lottery.insert(0, first_num);
    lottery.insert(1, second_num);
    lottery.insert(2, third_num);
    lottery.insert(3, fourth_num);
    lottery.insert(4, fifth_num);
    println!("{:?}", lottery);

    for i in 0..10 {
        lottery.get_mut(&0).unwrap().insert(i, Vec::<String>::new());
        lottery.get_mut(&1).unwrap().insert(i, Vec::<String>::new());
        lottery.get_mut(&2).unwrap().insert(i, Vec::<String>::new());
        lottery.get_mut(&3).unwrap().insert(i, Vec::<String>::new());
        lottery.get_mut(&4).unwrap().insert(i, Vec::<String>::new());
    }

    // add some test data
    let ticket1: [i32; 5] = [5, 3, 0, 9, 1];
    let ticket2: [i32; 5] = [1, 3, 0, 8, 2];
    let ticket3: [i32; 5] = [5, 3, 6, 9, 9];

    for i in 0..5 {
        lottery
            .get_mut(&(i as i32))
            .unwrap()
            .get_mut(&ticket1[i])
            .unwrap()
            .push("ticket1".to_owned());
        lottery
            .get_mut(&(i as i32))
            .unwrap()
            .get_mut(&ticket2[i])
            .unwrap()
            .push("ticket2".to_owned());
        lottery
            .get_mut(&(i as i32))
            .unwrap()
            .get_mut(&ticket3[i])
            .unwrap()
            .push("ticket3".to_owned());
    }
    println!("{:?}", lottery.get(&0));
    println!("{:?}", lottery.get(&1));
    println!("{:?}", lottery.get(&2));
    println!("{:?}", lottery.get(&3));
    println!("{:?}", lottery.get(&4));

    // find the winners
    println!("======================================");
    let matches_first_1 = lottery.get(&0).unwrap().get(&jackpot[0]).unwrap();
    println!("matches_first_1: {:?}", matches_first_1);

    let matches_first_2 = matches_first_1
        .iter()
        .cloned()
        .filter(|x| {
            lottery
                .get(&1)
                .unwrap()
                .get(&jackpot[1])
                .unwrap()
                .iter()
                .any(|y| x == y)
        })
        .map(|x| x)
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    println!("matches_first_2: {:?}", matches_first_2);

    let matches_first_3 = matches_first_2
        .iter()
        .cloned()
        .filter(|x| {
            lottery
                .get(&2)
                .unwrap()
                .get(&jackpot[2])
                .unwrap()
                .iter()
                .any(|y| x == y)
        })
        .map(|x| x)
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    println!("matches_first_3: {:?}", matches_first_3);

    let matches_first_4 = matches_first_3
        .iter()
        .cloned()
        .filter(|x| {
            lottery
                .get(&3)
                .unwrap()
                .get(&jackpot[3])
                .unwrap()
                .iter()
                .any(|y| x == y)
        })
        .map(|x| x)
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    println!("matches_first_4: {:?}", matches_first_4);

    let matches_first_5 = matches_first_4
        .iter()
        .cloned()
        .filter(|x| {
            lottery
                .get(&4)
                .unwrap()
                .get(&jackpot[4])
                .unwrap()
                .iter()
                .any(|y| x == y)
        })
        .map(|x| x)
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    println!("matches_first_5: {:?}", matches_first_5);
}
```

```
jackpot: [5, 3, 6, 9, 9]
==================================== Lottery (new code)
{1: {}, 3: {}, 4: {}, 0: {}, 2: {}}
Some({7: [], 0: [], 8: [], 2: [], 3: [], 4: [], 6: [], 9: [], 1: ["ticket2"], 5: ["ticket1", "ticket3"]})
Some({5: [], 7: [], 0: [], 9: [], 1: [], 6: [], 2: [], 4: [], 8: [], 3: ["ticket1", "ticket2", "ticket3"]})
Some({4: [], 1: [], 0: ["ticket1", "ticket2"], 3: [], 7: [], 9: [], 2: [], 8: [], 5: [], 6: ["ticket3"]})
Some({9: ["ticket1", "ticket3"], 1: [], 5: [], 4: [], 7: [], 2: [], 0: [], 6: [], 3: [], 8: ["ticket2"]})
Some({7: [], 4: [], 1: ["ticket1"], 8: [], 9: ["ticket3"], 0: [], 5: [], 3: [], 6: [], 2: ["ticket2"]})
======================================
matches_first_1: ["ticket1", "ticket3"]
matches_first_2: ["ticket1", "ticket3"]
matches_first_3: ["ticket3"]
matches_first_4: ["ticket3"]
matches_first_5: ["ticket3"]
```

Hint: Don't write all of those chained calls on a single line, and use a tool like VSCode's rust-analyzer plugin to get type hints. With that, you would have seen that something is off with your types.

---

A couple of tips, though:

- Don't use a `HashMap` if your indices are `0..9` - don't even use a `Vec`. Use an array. Your size is known at compile time, which makes an array the perfect candidate for your data structure. This brings your entire `lottery` initialization down to this single line:

  ```rust
  let mut lottery: [[Vec<String>; 10]; 5] = Default::default();
  ```
- Write an `insert_ticket` function to avoid code duplication. That brings your code down another couple of lines.
- Don't use `i32` as your value. As you need it as `usize` at certain points, conversion from signed to unsigned always requires an `as`, and casting numbers with `as` is risky. Always try to use `.into()` or `.from()`. Those are implemented for numbers that can be converted into each other without loss of data. In your case, all your ticket numbers fit in `u8` and `u8` can always be cast into `usize`, so use that type.
- Don't use `.get().unwrap()`. That's just pointless. Use the `[]` operator directly, which is a short form of `.get().unwrap()`. Especially now that we are using arrays, with `[]`, many of the out-of-bounds checks will get moved to compile time.

```rust
fn main() {
    let jackpot: [u8; 5] = [5, 3, 6, 9, 9];
    println!("jackpot: {:?}", jackpot);

    println!("==================================== Lottery (new code)");
    let mut lottery: [[Vec<String>; 10]; 5] = Default::default();
    println!("{:?}", lottery);

    // add some test data
    let ticket1: [u8; 5] = [5, 3, 0, 9, 1];
    let ticket2: [u8; 5] = [1, 3, 0, 8, 2];
    let ticket3: [u8; 5] = [5, 3, 6, 9, 9];

    fn insert_ticket(lottery: &mut [[Vec<String>; 10]; 5], ticket: [u8; 5], name: &str) {
        for i in 0..5 {
            lottery[i][usize::from(ticket[i])].push(name.to_string());
        }
    }
    insert_ticket(&mut lottery, ticket1, "ticket1");
    insert_ticket(&mut lottery, ticket2, "ticket2");
    insert_ticket(&mut lottery, ticket3, "ticket3");

    println!("{:?}", lottery[0]);
    println!("{:?}", lottery[1]);
    println!("{:?}", lottery[2]);
    println!("{:?}", lottery[3]);
    println!("{:?}", lottery[4]);

    // find the winners
    println!("======================================");
    let matches_first_1 = &lottery[0][usize::from(jackpot[0])];
    println!("matches_first_1: {:?}", matches_first_1);
    let matches_first_2 = matches_first_1
        .into_iter()
        .cloned()
        .filter(|x| lottery[1][usize::from(jackpot[1])].contains(x))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    println!("matches_first_2: {:?}", matches_first_2);
    let matches_first_3 = matches_first_2
        .into_iter()
        .filter(|x| lottery[2][usize::from(jackpot[2])].contains(x))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    println!("matches_first_3: {:?}", matches_first_3);
    let matches_first_4 = matches_first_3
        .into_iter()
        .filter(|x| lottery[3][usize::from(jackpot[3])].contains(x))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    println!("matches_first_4: {:?}", matches_first_4);
    let matches_first_5 = matches_first_4
        .into_iter()
        .filter(|x| lottery[4][usize::from(jackpot[4])].contains(x))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    println!("matches_first_5: {:?}", matches_first_5);
}
```

```
jackpot: [5, 3, 6, 9, 9]
==================================== Lottery (new code)
[[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]]
[[], ["ticket2"], [], [], [], ["ticket1", "ticket3"], [], [], [], []]
[[], [], [], ["ticket1", "ticket2", "ticket3"], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[["ticket1", "ticket2"], [], [], [], [], [], ["ticket3"], [], [], []]
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], ["ticket2"], ["ticket1", "ticket3"]]
[[], ["ticket1"], ["ticket2"], [], [], [], [], [], [], ["ticket3"]]
======================================
matches_first_1: ["ticket1", "ticket3"]
matches_first_2: ["ticket1", "ticket3"]
matches_first_3: ["ticket3"]
matches_first_4: ["ticket3"]
matches_first_5: ["ticket3"]
```

---

Further suggestions:

- Don't do all of this in-line, use structs instead. Like this:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Lottery {
    tickets: [[Vec<String>; 10]; 5],
}

impl Lottery {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            tickets: Default::default(),
        }
    }

    pub fn add_ticket(&mut self, ticket: &[u8; 5], name: &str) {
        for i in 0..5 {
            self.tickets[i][usize::from(ticket[i])].push(name.to_string());
        }
    }

    fn filter_tickets(&self, inp: &[String], position: usize, number: u8) -> Vec<String> {
        inp.into_iter()
            .filter(|x| self.tickets[position][usize::from(number)].contains(x))
            .cloned()
            .collect()
    }

    pub fn get_matches(&self, jackpot: &[u8; 5]) -> [Vec<String>; 5] {
        let winning_tickets_0 = self.tickets[0][usize::from(jackpot[0])].clone();
        let winning_tickets_1 = self.filter_tickets(&winning_tickets_0, 1, jackpot[1]);
        let winning_tickets_2 = self.filter_tickets(&winning_tickets_1, 2, jackpot[2]);
        let winning_tickets_3 = self.filter_tickets(&winning_tickets_2, 3, jackpot[3]);
        let winning_tickets_4 = self.filter_tickets(&winning_tickets_3, 4, jackpot[4]);

        [
            winning_tickets_0,
            winning_tickets_1,
            winning_tickets_2,
            winning_tickets_3,
            winning_tickets_4,
        ]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let jackpot: [u8; 5] = [5, 3, 6, 9, 9];
    println!("jackpot: {:?}", jackpot);

    println!("==================================== Lottery (new code)");
    let mut lottery = Lottery::new();
    println!("{:?}", lottery);

    // add some test data
    let ticket1: [u8; 5] = [5, 3, 0, 9, 1];
    let ticket2: [u8; 5] = [1, 3, 0, 8, 2];
    let ticket3: [u8; 5] = [5, 3, 6, 9, 9];

    lottery.add_ticket(&ticket1, "ticket1");
    lottery.add_ticket(&ticket2, "ticket2");
    lottery.add_ticket(&ticket3, "ticket3");

    println!("{:?}", lottery.tickets[0]);
    println!("{:?}", lottery.tickets[1]);
    println!("{:?}", lottery.tickets[2]);
    println!("{:?}", lottery.tickets[3]);
    println!("{:?}", lottery.tickets[4]);

    // find the winners
    println!("======================================");
    let winners = lottery.get_matches(&jackpot);
    println!("matches_first_1: {:?}", winners[0]);
    println!("matches_first_2: {:?}", winners[1]);
    println!("matches_first_3: {:?}", winners[2]);
    println!("matches_first_4: {:?}", winners[3]);
    println!("matches_first_5: {:?}", winners[4]);
}
```

```
jackpot: [5, 3, 6, 9, 9]
==================================== Lottery (new code)
Lottery { tickets: [[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]] }
[[], ["ticket2"], [], [], [], ["ticket1", "ticket3"], [], [], [], []]
[[], [], [], ["ticket1", "ticket2", "ticket3"], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[["ticket1", "ticket2"], [], [], [], [], [], ["ticket3"], [], [], []]
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], ["ticket2"], ["ticket1", "ticket3"]]
[[], ["ticket1"], ["ticket2"], [], [], [], [], [], [], ["ticket3"]]
======================================
matches_first_1: ["ticket1", "ticket3"]
matches_first_2: ["ticket1", "ticket3"]
matches_first_3: ["ticket3"]
matches_first_4: ["ticket3"]
matches_first_5: ["ticket3"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Do you know a good book or reference to learn advanced Rust? Most resources are just repeating basic stuff and not things like `unwrap`, `Option` and how things are really working under the hood.

Comment: I learned most of my knowledge from competitions/challenges. I especially learned a lot from [codewars.com](https://codewars.com); it gives you increasingly hard challenges, and once you solved them, you can see how other people solved them as well, and you can vote on other people's solutions. That way I learned a lot of best practices. And then, [Advent of Code](https://adventofcode.com/) is currently on :) I strongly recommend that ;)

Comment: But in general, practice, practice, practice :) Combined with youtube videos, of course the [official Rust std lib documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/), and stackoverflow ;) And of course the [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/), which should be the first thing everyone should read.

Comment: Also there is the [Rust tips](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) page on stackoverflow with some links in it.